# Best practice to write and delete contents from a File concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, nio

I am trying to implement a solution to write and delete the contents from a file using multiple threads (multiple writer threads and single delete thread). I am using `RandomAccessFile` and going through the NIO package documentation to find a best and fastest way to do it using Java. I also want to restore a pointer to the location/row last written and deleted in case JVM shuts down gracefully.

Can someone please advice a strategy to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It sounds like you're trying to implement a database, in which case the best practice is to not write one yourself but to use an existing system.

Comment: Yeah, kind of a database, but on a fly, I send data to external system (MQs, DBs) but i want to have the safe copy of data in the local disk before I send to those external systems, will be helpful is preventing data loss in case the external systems go down.

Comment: @Gordon Do You belive, that Your solution will be better designed & tested. mode safe than existing software? Way, You give a question show (in my opinion) totally don't understand problems waiting for project. Read abut key-value databases

Comment: See `commit log` which is an immutable append structure to fulfill that requirement

Comment: Found my answer in persistent queues, @Jacek i think i understand the problems and that is the reason why I came here looking for expert opinions. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Gordon I think it is good if you can update your question with your specific problem? Otherwise your question is far too abstract to answer.

Comment: @Supun, my problem is writing and deleting from a file concurrently, multiple threads to write and single thread to delete, row by row